# Script Engine for Android development with Mono

Tags: javascript, android, mono

Is there any script interpreter that has coroutines, generators, or iterators so that they can be used to achieve asynchronous like behavior? Something that is also compatible with Mono. I have tried Jint, and Jurassic but neither of these two support generators and the interpreter treats them as a syntax error. I have searched but have not been able to find anything other than these two, so any recommendations are surely appreciated.

Comment: Android's Webview (api39+) supports Generators and has basic support for yield(*), etc...

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.